# Response JSONString order not correctly after reading in iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have JSONString from api as bellow:
[JSONString from api]

[image]

But after I read in iOS from Alamofire the order of the JSONString is not correct as api:
[JSON After read in iOS]

[image]

How can I keep the JSON format the same order as api?

Comment: It can be different order because of your JSON is Dictionary which is unordered type.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Nimit, JSON format represented in your callback and the API response is of least concern. What you need to care about is that when you are accessing the values from the response, the KEY should be same as seen in the API. No mismatch, not even of the case-sensitive letter, or you will always get the NIL in the response.

To explain it better to you with the use of Alamofire, let's me show you one example:

```
let APIURL = "https://api.yoururl.com"

Alamofire.request(.GET, APIURL , headers: headers) .responseJSON { response in

            let value = response.result.value!
            let JSONRes = JSON(value)
            let KLValue = JSONRes["Kuala Lumpur"].int!
            print(KLValue) //Or call a function to handle the callback
}
```

Here I am using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for JSON. In the end, all you want to do is get the data out of the associated keys in the JSON response, no need to worry about how they have been formatted, or what's the order of Keys in the response - most of the time you will get the same as in the API - but in case it changes, need not to worry.

On the another front, to be sure that nothing happens to your app when JSON fields are nil, always put an if-let like this:

```
if let valueFromJSON = JSONRes["Kuala Lumpur"].string {
     someVariable = valueFromJSON
   } else {
     someVariable = "No Value" 
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have no problem with reading JSON everything working find just only the order after get from Alamofire is not the same as the response from api.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, unless you write your own JSON parser. Any self-respecting JSON library won't guarantee you the order, if it wants to conform to the JSON spec.

From the definition of the JSON object:

> the NSDictionary class represents an unordered collection of objects;
>   however, they associate each value with a key, which acts like a label
>   for the value. This is useful for modeling relationships between pairs
>   of objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a jsonObject, such as data, then you can convert to json string like this:

```
let jsonString = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data,
                                        options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys)
```

when you use sortedKeys option, the json will be specifies that the output sorts keys in lexicographic order.